# Regular Expressions # of /

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to incorporate a regex into my bs4 project.

```
<a href="/event/football">football</a>
<a href="/event/rugby-union">Rugby Union</a>
<a href="/event/ladies/football">Ladies Soccer</a>
<a href="/event/womens/rugby-union">Womens Rugby</a>
```

I would like to only match the first two where there is only 2 forward slashes. I have tried the code below but it doesn't work. I am very poor with regex so would appreciate some help

```
for event in events.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/event/[^/]')):
```

Comment: Try `r'^/event/[^/]+$'`

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. One more thing, I also would like to exclude and href with the word cancelled in it. I tried adding [^/cancelled] but excluded anything that contained c or a etc. How do I add cancelled as just one word?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match any `/event/....` but `/event/cancelled`?

Comment: any event unless it ends in -cancelled so event/rugby-union will match but event/rugby-league-cancelled will not

Comment: See my answer with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any href with only 2 parts inside, you need

```
r'^/event/[^/]+$'
              ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXewTg/1).

The `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern and the `$` anchor matches the end of string, so no more parts are allowed.

To disallow all href values ending with `-cancelled`, add a negative lookahead (`(?!.*-cancelled$)` will fail the match if `/event/` is followed with any 0+ chars followed with `-cancelled` at the end of string (`$`)):

```
r'^/event/(?!.*-cancelled$)[^/]+$'
```

([demo here](https://regex101.com/r/UXewTg/2)) or with a lookbehind (the `(?<!-cancelled)` will be executed once after reaching the end of string and will fail the match if there is `-cancelled` right at the end of string):

```
r'^/event/[^/]+$(?<!-cancelled)'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXewTg/4).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a `+` after your character set, so it matches more than just one character:

```
for event in events.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/event/[^/]+'))
#                                                              ^
```